# MongoDB - Can't read data from the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller

hi I am a newbie and am facing an issue.I am doing a rideshare cab application and am getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error` in jade file.

My jade file is as follows:-

```
html
  body
    h1 Passengers List
    each user in users
      script(type='text/javascript').
        function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
        var checkgroup=checkgroup
        var limit=limit
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
        checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
        var checkedcount=0
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
        checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
        if (checkedcount>limit){
        this.checked=false
        }
        }
        }
        }
      p Select your passenger below:
      form#world(name='man')
        input(type='checkbox', name='dude')
        |  li {passenger.name}
        br
      script(type='text/javascript').
        //Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)
        checkboxlimit(document.forms.man.dude, 4)
```

In this file i am trying to display all the users and let the driver select four passengers..

Once done I will create a new jade file to display the driver and the passenger associated with the driver

The following is my serverjs snippet:-

```
app.post('/passenger',function(req,res){
        var user = new User({profile:{name:req.body.uname},
        type:"passenger",
        phone_no:req.body.contact,
        origin:{city:req.body.pick},
        destination:{city:req.body.drop}
      //  email:req.body.email,
    //    password:req.body.password
    })
         user.save();
       //  passengers.push(user)
       //  console.log(passengers)

        res.render('checkbox', {user: user});
       // res.redirect('/checkbox')
    });   

app.get('/checkbox',function(req,res){
        res.render('checkbox');
    });
```

my model is as follows:-

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: String,
  facebook: String,
  google: String,
  origin: {city: String, state: String},
  destination: {city: String, state: String},
  price: Array,
  time: Date,
  phone_no: String,
  accepted:String,
  tokens: Array,
  type: String,
  profile: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    gender: { type: String, default: '' },
    location: { type: String, default: '' },
    website: { type: String, default: '' },
    picture: { type: String, default: '' }
  },

  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date
});
```

I cant seem to understand what is wrong in the code..Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: What data are you passing as users?

Comment: @Bwaxxlo I am trying to fetch the data from the database..

Comment: If you don't have any data present, the section `checkgroup.length` will automatically fail. Wrap the logic in a conditional for only when there's data present.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo I am having the data in the database..I am getting what you are trying to save but how do i display the data from database

Comment: To display the data, you need to make sure you're able to pull the data from your DB. The length error is a flag that you're not pulling the data correctly. Make sure your function for loading data works (i.e: test it without jade first to make sure you can load data from the DB)

Comment: @Bwaxxlo i am not able to fetch data from database..Where am i going wrong..Actually the data is getting saved in the database

Comment: That depends entirely on your ORM and how you connect to the DB. Start with this for basic MongoDB queries: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/.

I'm sorry, my mongodb knowledge is limited

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {};
x.someProperty; //this is undefined
x.someProperty.length; // Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

So, you are trying to get the property of an undefined. Try to find in which part of the code you are trying to get `length`.

`function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit) {` pay attention to this line, checkgroup its `undefined`.

And this `var checkgroup=checkgroup`, `var limit=limit` is pointless.

=)

Comment: I am getting the issue in each user in users